# Ошибка на Python

Tags: python

Вылезает такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
  "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\project\main.py", line 5, in <module>
     import settings   File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\project\settings.py", line 36
     rules = '''Используя наш бот, вы соглашаетесь со следующими правилами:\n\n IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Я хотел сделать новую кнопку.

Код **menu.py**:

```py
main_menu.add(
types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=' Правила', callback_data='rules'),
)
```

**main.py**

```py
 if call.data == 'rules':
    bot.edit_message_text(
        chat_id=chat_id,
        message_id=message_id,
        text=settings.rules,
        reply_markup=menu.main_menu
    )
```

**settings.py**

```py
rules = '''Используя наш бот, вы соглашаетесь со следующими правилами:\n\n

Общие положения и условия пользования: Используя наш бот вы сознательно автоматически соглашаетесь с нашими правилами:\n

 - администрацией может быть отказано в предоставлении услуг пользователю, без объяснения на то каких-либо причин и преследуемых мотивов;\n
 - мы не делаем возврат средств с баланса аккаунта;\n
 - все платежи могут быть осуществлены только через платёжную систему "Qiwi" и чеком от "BTC Banker";\n
 - мы не даем никаких гарантий, что купленные Вами карты имеют положительный баланс, следовательно, это не является причиной их замены. Если карта не подтверждена службой безопасности VISA или 3D MC Protect, мы не сможем осуществить замену;\n
 - мы не заменяем карты с неправильным адресом, штатом, городом, индексом, телефоном, DOB, SSN, MMN или именем; - данные карт берутся с формы сниффера, куда владелец вводит собственноручно информацию, вот числе ccv,exp, cvv, avs;\n
 - мы не гарантируем точность предоставляемой нами дополнительной информации о владельце карты, такой как штат, город, почтовый индекс, адрес, телефон, DOB, SSN и т.д.;\n

Поддержка:\n\n

 Поддержка предоставляется посредством чата с представителем службы тех. поддержки - @markttrt.\n
 По вопросам сотрудничества - @kodaine.\n
 - обращаясь в службу поддержки, старайтесь максимально описать суть проблемы и ваши ожидания для ее решения.\n
 - вопросы по поводу несоответствия биллинговой информация либо баланса на карте - не рассматриваются и будут проигнорированы;\n
 - просьбы, запросы, требования касательно добавления определенных BIN-ов или стран - не рассматриваются и будут лишены какого-либо ответа с нашей стороны.\n


Способ общения с поддержкой: \n

Мы убедительно просим Вас общаться с поддержкой исключительно вежливо, соблюдая все правила делового общения, мы изначально настроены на позитивное отношение к Вам. Также в спорные моменты стиль Вашего общения может сыграть ключевую роль в результате решения ряда вопросов\n


Уважаемые пользователи! Правила могут быть обновлены - пожалуйста, обратите на это внимание.'''
```

Comment: Можете отредактировать код в вопросе?

Comment: rules - это строка? поместите текст в кавычки, не в тройные

Comment: IndentationError: unexpected indent означает неправильные или смешанные отступы. зачем у Вас ``` перед rules?

Comment: ``` для чего ? этож не кавычки ' или "

Comment: Ошибка unexpected indent говорит о том, что у вас отступ там, где его не должно быть. Похоже, что прямо перед `rules =`, хотя в коде в вопросе этого нет.

Comment: @insolor сразу скажу код не мой.  В коде так же стоят другие кнопки , с такими же отступами . И все работает прекрасно. Не знаю в чем у меня проблема

Comment: @Jack_oS rules = это Код

Comment: @Batyr, еще раз: в вашем файле settings.py слева от `rules = ` есть лишний отступ (пробелы или табы). Об этом и говорит ошибка. Нужно лишние отступ убрать.

Comment: @insolor https://imgur.com/a/YmxizYJ где тут лишний отступ или таб? не могу найти. Часов 5 просидел уже

Comment: @Batyr, пробел слева от слова rules, которое волнистой чертой подчеркнуто.